# Assigning a condition to a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, generator

Is there a way to assign a condition to a variable in Python?

Specifically, I am writing a generator that is infinite by default, limited by choice. This code works but the duplication is ugly:

```
def generate(start=0, stop=None):
    i = start

    if stop == None:
        while True:
            yield i
            i += 1
    else:
        while i <= stop:
            yield i
            i += 1
```

Specifically, I would like to express something like this:

```
def generate(start=0, stop=None):
    i = start

    if stop == None:
        condition = True
    else:
        condition = 'i <= stop' # Of course, this will throw an error

    while condition:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: `while stop is None or i <= stop:`

Comment: @dano Thanks. Nice idea. But isn't that less than optimal given that the interpreter has an extra check to perform at each iteration?

Comment: you could just `raise(StopIteration)`.. but yea, dano's answer is best

Comment: @TehTris Can you elaborate?

Comment: @zadrozny Yes, but the performance hit from introducing a single extra check is negligible, unless you've got very high performance expectations. And in that case a pure python implementation probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: @zadrozny Also, I think the only other alternatives would involve adding a function call to the while loop. Function calls are very expensive in Python, and probably add more overhead than an extra check to the while loop.

Comment: zadrozny, no extra check is performed in @dano solution. The second check is performed ONLY if the first check returns False. It is called lazy evaluation. Try it out with a sample script.

Comment: @helloV That does mean that each iteration does an extra check (`stop is None`) if `stop` is defined as something other than `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reimplementing itertools.count and itertools takewhile.

Count forever forever:

```
itertools.count()
```

Count upto stop:

```
itertools.takewhile(lambda a: a <= stop, itertools.count())
```

But maybe this is a dumbed down example, and maybe making the condition a function is the answer you are looking for:

```
def generate(start=0, stop=None):
    i = start

    if stop == None:
        condition = lambda _: True
    else:
        condition = lambda x: x <= stop

    while condition(i):
        yield i
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of using lambda. I'm refactoring a prime number generator to include an optional start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def gener(x):
     for item in range(x):
             if item == 5:
                     raise(StopIteration)
             yield(item)
```

this is an example of a generator that wont go past 5.

```
>>> a = gener(7)
>>> [x for x in a]
>>>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This works, because `StopIteration` is a built in exception that is raised by the generator object when you reach the end of a generators output

```
>>> def gen(): #the most basic generator
...     for item in range(3): yield item
...
>>>
>>> a = gen()
>>> a.next()
0
>>> a.next()
1
>>> a.next()
2
>>> a.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

when it reaches the end it naturally raises `StopIteration` as you can see... so raise it yourself, if you want to stop iterating.... I am unsure as to how pythonic this is.... to me it kinda feels alright though, lol